# React Hydrate warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain the text node "Mika"

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to hydrate a server side rendered React app.

The issue is, always getting warning:

```
warning.js:33 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain the text node "Mika" in <section>
```

I am trying to render a single component

```jsx
class Home extends Component {
  constructor( props ) { super( props ) }
  render(){
    return "Mika"
  }
}
```

And when viewing the page source I get,

```html
<section id="rootNode">Mika</section>
```

One more thing I have noticed, when I send an empty content, i didn't get the warning and react injects the content "Mika"

```html
<section id="rootNode"></section>
```